# Fragmentation when creating non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index, fragmentation

When I was dealing with fragmentation, I had a question about a non-clustered index. In non-clustered index actual table data (typically stored in a clustered index, otherwise a heap) is stored separately from the non-clustered index.
How does this impact table and index fragmentation when I create non-clustered index?

I appreciate a detailed response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In non-clustered index the data is stored in one place, and the index is stored in another place.

I don't understand this statement. The nonclustered indexes data is part of the nonclustered index.

If you mean the actual table data (typically stored in a clustered index, otherwise a heap) is stored separately from the nonclustered index, then yea sure, that's true.

> How does this impact fragmentation when I create non-clustered index?

Again, it's unclear if you mean the fragmentation of the nonclustered index itself, or the fragmentation of the table instead. Each logical data storage object is liable to fragmentation.

Regardless, fragmentation doesn't affect performance or really cause much harm these days, especially since mechanical hard drives aren't really used anymore. So the answer is it doesn't matter.

Comment: thx that you corrected me and answering my question.  The last thing I want to clarify how non-clustered index will become insufficient by the time. It is all about non-leaf levels? I will be very grateful for your response.

Comment: @volodya_neftyannik np! Indexes typically never become insufficient if the queries don't change. If someone writes a different query that isn't covered by the index then the index will potentially need to be updated, or a new one created possibly.

Comment: @J.D. fragmentation does take place and it will affect performance .As I technical person we should know it and way to overcome irrespective of hard drive.HARD Drive arent mechanical these days,this mean what instead of DBA you hire layman :)

Comment: @KumarHarsh "*and it will affect performance...hard drive.HARD Drive arent mechanical these days,this mean what instead of DBA you hire layman*" - Nope, it means hard drives are significantly faster these days than they used to be such that fragmentation doesn't affect things much anymore. It's misinformation to worry about it nowadays, and actually wasteful to run index maintenance to try to fix it.

Comment: @J.D.I Got your point.I meant if any "fragmentation happening" one should be aware of it and take precautionary measure irrespective of hard drive

Comment: @KumarHarsh "*I meant if any "fragmentation happening" one should be aware of it and take precautionary measure irrespective of hard drive*" - There's nothing precautionary to do, fragmentation is normal. Index Maintenance is a reactionary way to respond to it, but it's not needed. So simply put, there's no reason to be concerned with index fragmentation.